# Dynamics NAV Page translations

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision

I have multilanguage translations on table and when I create page which have fields from that table there are some other translations on few fields.
What can cause such problem?

Thanks :)

Comment: Screenshot please.

Comment: Tnx, but I solved it

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: Some IDs on page were in conflict with some other IDs so I just changed the IDs of these fields